# Easy differential equation without Integral calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I heve the following easy differential equation:

$$(1+e^x)y\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x$$

It easy to solve it by change of variable and integrals.

But... how do you solve it using only Differential Calculus arguments? That is: without integrals. Indeed, I can't use uniqueness theorem

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $(1+\text{e}^x)$:
$$
y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\text{e}^x}{\text{e}^x+1}.
$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$
\int y \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int \frac{\text{e}^x}{\text{e}^x+1} dx.
$$

Left side is $\frac{y^2}{2}$, right side is $\text{ln} (\text{e}^x+1)$, so:

$$
\frac{y^2}{2} = \text{ln}(\text{e}^x+1) + C
$$
which defines the solution $y$ implicitly.

Comment: I only can use differential calculus. Integrals are not permited.

Comment: @sinbadh can you use some kind of "guessing" which function has this or that derivative?

Comment: I can use some physics interpretation